# Is it possible to get information such as SparkContext.appName within the mapPartitionsWithIndex?

Tags: debugging, apache-spark

What I am trying to accomplish is to get as much information as possible from within the mapPartitionsWithIndex.

If I try to get something like sc.appName, the NullPointerException is thrown.

How do I obtain as much information as I can from within the mapPartitionsWithIndex ?

-I need this for debugging and seeing what is actually happening while processing an RDD. For example, it would useful to know which csv file is being processed and on which slave. All solutions I got were outside the mapPartitionsWithIndex.

Comment: Why would you want to get `sc.appName` on the executors? It will be the same name on all of them... Perhaps you could say what you're trying to do.

Comment: I thought I already explained that by "How do I obtain as much information as I can from within the mapPartitionsWithIndex ?" What I am trying to do is to get as much information as I can about the executor, from within the executor while it is executed.

Comment: `sc.appName` is not "information about the executor". It's about the application. I'm not sure what information you're looking for. In my answer I show how to get the hostname as an example. If you just want as much information as possible, I recommend downloading Wikipedia :).

Comment: getHostName is a partial answer, and it is not a Spark-related but java.net related. downloading wikipedia dumps means nothing.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you specified _what_ information you are looking for.

Comment: @Daniel, any information regarding the executor, for example, what file(s) it processed from RDD that is loaded as an s3 bucket with all files ending in "csv", when, etc. So if it fails I need to see what information and in what file caused it to fail. Nevertheless, I would also like to post as much information about it as possible. Using java.net is a partial answer because I need something that can be found within the Spark API. Also, using multiple spark contexts is not supported, and SparkContext is not serializable so that doesn't help me either...

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot pass a `SparkContext` to the executors. (`SparkContext` is not `Serializable`.) But you can pass `sc.appName` (or any other `Serializable` value):

```
val appName = sc.appName
rdd.mapPartitions(p => Iterator(appName))
```

You can also access the local (executor) environment, for example:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(p => Iterator(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName))
```

You also mention learning which CSV file is being processed. Let's say your code is like this:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(".../directory/*.csv")
rdd.mapPartitions { partition =>
  partition.map { line =>
    // What file is "line" from?
    ???
  }
}
```

The question at that point cannot be answered.

*Before* calling `mapPartitions` you may be able to figure out what belongs to what partition. This is pre-destined even before any code is executed on the executors. (Check out the code in [HadoopRDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala).) But this would require you to inspect a member (`inputSplit`) of a private class (`HadoopPartition`), and other tinkering. Best not go there.

Instead you should use `sc.wholeTextFiles`:

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles(".../directory/*.csv")
rdd.flatMap { case (file, contents) =>
  contents.split("\n", -1).map { line =>
    // "line" is from "file"!
    ???
  }
}
```

Comment: Again, this is a partial answer and only answering the part about the SparkContext.

Comment: I've added a method for telling which CSV file a line is from. Note that it does not require passing `sc.appName` to the executor, which was your question.

Comment: Ah, glad to hear I managed to help! Sorry for going in circles at the beginning.

Comment: Mind if I bore you for a moment?  if I do:: rdd.flatMap { case (file, contents) => "test123"} :: I get the error that file is not found, perhaps because I am running the master with two slaves on ec2.  Do you know why ?

Comment: Huh, no idea. At the point where you have `(file, contents)` the file would have already been read. Perhaps it's best for a separate question, just be sure to include the line that reads the files (`sc.wholeTextFiles`). Oh, one idea: if you're using S3, the path should look like `s3n://bucket/file`. Note that it's `s3n://`, not `s3://`.

Comment: It looks like I am getting just the key without the s3n://bucketname part.